# Winter Dash 2020, Wearing a hat that is not owned

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash-2020

Yesterday I had for example 12 hats, then the next day it decreased to 10. 
After that I wore a hat like this because of the glitch effect when I wanted to wear a hat.

[image: Use Hat]

But I don't have that hat in Winter Dash section

[image: Not have Winterdash Hat]

Why can this happen if I don't have it?

Comment: Same for me... with the headphones hat (Disciple) too.

Comment: Well, it *is* a secret hat - perhaps it is so secret they can't tell you how/where you got it...